# TestDrive equivalent for Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, virtualization, automation, kvm-virtualization

Every now and then I'd like to play with a fresh minimal install of Ubuntu (to test sysadminish scripts, application install instructions, package dependency lists etc.).

I'd like to have a tool as **simple to use** as [testdrive](https://launchpad.net/testdrive): pick a version (say, 'maverick'), run a command, get a shell in a new virtual machine.

I'd like that shell to be in the current terminal, rather than a new GUI window that testdrive uses.  Setting up the new VM to accept SSH logins with my ssh public key is fine.

I'd like the VM to have network access out of the box; NAT to a virtual network interface is fine.

Why a VM?  Chroots don't really cut it: installing, say, Apache in a chroot would fail because it would try to listen on port 80, which is already taken.  Containers might work, though, if there are any that are supported by standard Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) looked like a promising tool, but (1) it's not packaged for Ubuntu, and (2) it requires non-free software (VirtualBox non-OSE) to function.

Comment: [vmbuilder](https://launchpad.net/vmbuilder) is promising: `vmbuilder kvm ubuntu` gives me a new vm image and a run script in `./ubuntu-kvm/run.sh` in 5 minutes; the only problem is that I've no idea what to do with the VM.  The run script spawns a QEMU GUI window which says "Starting up...", eats 100% CPU, and never shows a login prompt.

Comment: Entering the GRUB menu in the VM and choosing recovery mode doesn't help either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/), while still not present in the standard Ubuntu repositories, now has a [ready-to-use .deb](http://downloads.vagrantup.com/tags/v1.0.0) and now works with virtualbox-ose.

Installation is as simple as

- install [virtualbox-ose](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/virtualbox-ose)
- download [vagrant_1.0.0_i686.deb](http://files.vagrantup.com/packages/aafa79fe66db687da265d790d5e67a2a7ec30d92/vagrant_1.0.0_i686.deb) (or [vagrant_1.0.0_x86_64.deb](http://files.vagrantup.com/packages/aafa79fe66db687da265d790d5e67a2a7ec30d92/vagrant_1.0.0_x86_64.deb)) from the website
- install it with the Software Center, or with `sudo dpkg -i vagrant_1.0.0_i686.deb`
- `sudo ln -s /opt/vagrant/bin/vagrant /usr/local/bin` to make it appear on your $PATH

Usage is as simple as

- `vagrant box add lucid32 http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box` (once)
- `mkdir sandbox && cd sandbox && vagrant init lucid32` (creates a ./Vagrantfile you can customize if you want)
- `vagrant up && vagrant ssh` (you're now in a shell session inside a new VM)
- `vagrant suspend` (or `halt`, or `destroy`) when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think this is an excellent suggestion, and definitely something that TestDrive could/should support!

In the meantime, you can grab a UEC image, untar it, and launch it in KVM:

```
wget http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/natty/current/natty-server-uec-amd64.tar.gz
tar zxvf *.tar.gz
kvm -boot a -fda natty-server-uec-amd64-floppy -drive file=natty-server-uec-amd64.img,if=virtio -curses
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This worked great for me on my natty machine. +1

Comment: I can't tell if it works or not -- I got the grub menu, chose ubuntu:ubuntu, and now kvm has been spinning for 10 minutes eating one full CPU core with no output on the console.  Ping scans on the virbr interface don't show any reachable machines either.  Should I wait more?  Should I hit some magic key sequence?  Should I fiddle with the kvm command line to enable networking?

Comment: I should've mentioned that I tried this with maverick-server-uec-i386.tar.gz on a maverick machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use TestDrive to launch a UEc Server Image. The way you can use it is:

```
testdrive -p uec-daily -l uec-server
```

When launching, it will show you grub, where you should select:

```
"uec-image with ubuntu:ubuntu"
```

You could also use TestDrive as follows, to specify the release. By default it will use natty:

```
testdrive -p uec-daily -l uec-server -r maverick
```

Comment: Presumably I would need a newer version of testdrive than the one available in Maverick, since that one complains: `testdrive: error: no such option: -p`

Comment: Marius,
I'll make available the new package in testdrive PPA by tomorrow so you can take a use of it. Cheers!

Comment: Uploaded to PPA for Maverick at:

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:testdrive/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install testdrive

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long for me to find the time to try this again.  I've added the testdrive PPA, upgraded testdrive to 3.13-0ubuntu1~ppa4, and tried `testdrive -p uec-daily -l uec-server`.  The command failed: `qemu-img: Could not open '/home/mg/.cache/testdrive/iso/uec-server_natty-server-uec-i386.img'`.  `ls` confirms that the file is actually named `natty-server-uec-i386.img`,

Comment: Natty's native testdrive 3.13-0ubuntu1 fails "testdrive -p uec-daily -l uec-server -r natty" in the same way (No such file or directory).

Comment: Same failure with "testdrive -p uec-daily -l uec-server -r maverick".

Comment: And same failure with "testdrive -p uec-daily -l uec-server", which tries oneiric.

Comment: Trying again in Oneiric: `testdrive -p uec-daily -l uec-server` gives one choice only: "Other (prompt for ISO URL)".  I've no idea what URL to supply.